# Java make 3rd-party class Serializable

Tags: java, serialization

Let's say, I have a class that was not written by me. And moreover, class if `final`.

How to make this class `Serializable`?

Comment: Read the fields via Reflection

Comment: One option may be to create a separate class that *is* serializable, that represents the non-serializable class. When you want to serialize, convert to the serializable class. After serialization, convert back to the non-serializable class.

Comment: @AndyThomas This could be quiet hard to implement if provided class is too big / deep

Comment: You could decompile it, and see if you have any chances. And note that some objects just can not be serialized, for example thin JNI wrappers for complex native code.

Comment: What is you goal? Why do you need it to be Serializable? I would say that is might be a bad idea if you don't know its internal structure/functionality. But if you need to write/restore its fields to/from a DB, for example, there are alternative solutions.